# Network request failed on iOS device || React-Native || expo

Tags: react-native, expo, api-platform.com

#### What I would like to do :

I'm try to send a request to my API (created with ApiPlatform) in local in my React Native app with my ios device on expo.
Could someone knows how to fix it ? :)

Here the request that I want to do : 
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/beers"

#### What works :

My request works on my computer

My request works on my android emulator by typing that :
"http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/beers"

#### What I've done :

For the ios Device on expo,
I've read that I need to change 127.0.0.1:8000 by the Ipv4 of my computer,
so I ran

```
ipconfig
```

in a powershell, and get my Ipv4 address, put in my request :
"http://172.20.10.2:8000/api/beers"

I've read that ios doesn't allow http protocole, so I add in my app.json  -> infoPlist -> NSAppTransportSecurity -> true

```
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSAppTransportSecurity" : {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true,
        }
      }
    }
```

. Like all the other topic said, but always the same error : "Network request failed"

I'm connected in the same network in both(iOS device and android emulator).

I've tried "https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/583" for example, and it works on my emulator and my iOS device.

I'm using other API but there are started by 'https'. Here the problem seem to be the 'http'.

However I tried to fixed it by add "NSAppTransportSecurity" : "true" in the infoPlist in the app.json, but nothing change. Like I say upper.

I've also try to connected to internet in an other home, change the IPv4. But still the issue.

I don't see other way to fix it. I probably miss something.

Here the function that permit the request

```
export function getsBeersFromRatio(){
    const url = Platform.OS === 'android'? 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/beers?abv%5Bgte%5D=6.2' : 'http://172.20.10.2:8000/api/beers'
    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}


  _searchBeersFromRatio(){
    this.setState({
      beers: [],
    },
    () => {
      this._loadBeersFromRatio()
    })
  }



  _loadBeersFromRatio(){
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log('       NEW REQUEST                   ');
    console.log('====================================');
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    getsBeersFromRatio().then(data => {
      console.log(data);

    })
  }


    <Button
      title = "get data from API"
      onPress = {() => this._searchBeersFromRatio()}
    />
```

Here my package.json :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "postinstall": "node ./scripts/stfu.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "country-list": "^2.1.1",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^2.6.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "rn-vertical-slider": "^1.0.4",
    "victory-native": "^32.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "BierRatio",
    "slug": "BierRatio",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSAppTransportSecurity" : {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Expected behavior

I expect the same log that my android emulator

#### Actual behavior

The actual output is "Network request failed"

Thank !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workaround :

I finally find a workaroud :

When I typed http://"My_IPv4_address":8000/"My_Api" on my computer, he said : **"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"**

So I tried to run $ **php bin/console server:run "My_IPv4_address":8000**

A firewall notification appears to me, I accept it.
I send my request again in my iOS device and I don't know why it works now.

So I need to run

$ **php bin/console server:run**

and in a other powershell

$ **php bin/console server:run "My_IPv4_address":8000**

to have access to my local API in my android emulator and my iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I use `fetch()` to send my data from my native react application to my php server, I simulate from my iOS phone with expo but I receive the same error as you while I have configured the correct IPV4 address

```
fetch (http: // ipv4 address / ...)
```

and not localhost.

Also when I simulate a web view on my pc and I put

```
fetch (http: // localhost / ..)
```

I receive the data everything works perfectly.